# File I/O in java and C#

Tags: java, c#

This java code is written for reading a text File which is like this:

```
AL  B  C  DF
E  FBI  GL  H
IB  J  K  LNH
```

java code:

```
  try{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(defaultFile));
      while ( (str = in.ReadLine()) != null) { 
          StringTokenizer es = new StringTokenizer(str, "\t");
          Parameter param = new Parameter(); 

          param.setParameterName(es.nextToken());
          param.setParameterType(es.nextToken());
          ...
          parameterVector.addElement(param);
       }
          in.Close();
    }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          return ("can not find valid default parameter file");
        }
```

I want to convert this code to C#. To be able to read the text file one line at a time( with respect to the column) I need to have something like a token. I could not find any equivalent for the StringTokenizer in C# so I thought about defining the space between the column like (' ') but it does not work for the str.columns(space) which is defined as an argument.

This is what I am doing :

```
try{
    System.IO.StreamReader inBuffer = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\WriteLines2.txt");

    while ( (str = inBuffer.ReadLine()) != null) {
        char[] space = {' '};
        string[] columns = str.Split(space);
        Parameter param = new Parameter();
            param.setParameterName(str.columns(space));
            param.setParameterType(str.columns(space));
    }
        inBuffer.Close();
    }
      catch (Exception ex) {
        return ("can not find valid default parameter file");
      }
```

Does anyone have any idea that how do I read a text file with respect to the columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then you will have to read it as the char[][] array to track line and column

Comment: The problem is that the text file elements have different sizes...let me to change the text file in the post

Comment: then u check if there is a space between elements and then u increase column value

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? What is Parameter? Where does it fail? More specific information on this will help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string[] columns = str.Split(new [] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then:

```
int i = 0;
Parameter param = new Parameter();
param.setParameterName(columns[i++]);
param.setParameterType(columns[i++]);
...
parameterVector.addElement(param);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, please check my new Edit for the text file.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you are spliting with `\t`.

Try to use

```
string [] values = str.split (new char [] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Parameter param = new Parameter();
int i=0;
if (i>=values.Length) continue;
param.setParameterName(values [i++]);
if (i>=values.Length) continue;
param.setParameterType(values [i++]);
...
```

Comment: And what will be the argument for the param.setParameterName(?) ?